# failed to redirect anounymous users with intercept url in spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing an application with authentication with  `spring security`.

I'm trying to avoid access to the jsp pages with writing url and access the application without authenticating.

I have this code which disable access to the pages without authenticating:

```
    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/accueil" 
        authentication-failure-url="/403" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" /> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/utilisateurs" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/serveurs" access="isAuthenticated()" />        
        <intercept-url pattern="/customizedDB" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/accueil" access="isAuthenticated()" />


        <logout   logout-success-url="/login.jsp" />

 </http>
```

My problem is that when I type url which necessitate authentication I'm redirected to a page `login` which inexistant !

this is what I had :

[image]

How can I change this redirection to another page (403.jsp for example )?

Comment: What about simply: `<form-login login-page="/403" ...` if you do not want anonymous users to be prompted for login?

Comment: this will display page `403.jsp` as a login page before authenticating.

Comment: you avoid this by creating a custom filter or protect every url